# How does government ethos change work in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

In Stellaris government ethos works on four scales:

- Pacifist-Militarist
- Authoritarian - Egalitarian
- Xenophobe - Xenophile
- Materialist - Spiritualist

[image]

At any stage empire can have only three ethics or one fanatical and one regular (i.e. you can be Pacifist-Egalitarian-Spiritualist* or Militarist-fanatical Xenophile**)

But you can change the ethos in game, either by rare and special events ("Shrines of the Old Gods" for example can make you more spiritual) or by embracing a faction within your empire (embracing pacifists would make you go towards "fanatical pacifist" for example)

But how is it determined which of the ethics you would loose? If I am xenophobe-pacifist-materialist and now want to go somewhere in the egalitarian-authoritarian scale, which ethic will I lose? Is it a random one or is there a specific rule?

<sup>*AKA "Space Hippies"</sup>

<sup>** They will love you, whether you want it or not! And they will make you love them!</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You lose the ethos with the least population support. Or the opposing one if you have, for example, pacifist and are going to embrace militarist.

Here is a dev diary about it: https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/stellaris-dev-diary-61-indoctrination-unrest-and-faction-interactions.999954/

In particular: "Which ethic is lost or added is determined by attraction, so if you are Spiritualist, Xenophobe and Authoritarian and make a shift towards Militarist, whichever of Spiritualist, Xenophobe and Authoritarian has the lowest attraction in your empire will be lost as a Governing Ethic."

Comment: Good find.  Deleting my answer.

Comment: Just a note from something that I've noticed yesterday: If you are embracing new ehtos and you have one fanatical one already, you will loose the fanatical one instead of one with the least population support.